# How jasper the jsp engine, compile JSP to servlet?

Tags: tomcat

is Jasper a Java compiler itself?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Jasper is Tomcat's JSP engine, which implements the JSP specification. It compiles JSP files to Java code. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat#Jasper) is the Wikipedia article.

Older versions of Tomcat used to require JDK in order to compile JSP files. This is no longer necessary, as Jasper can do this job.